# Is it impossible to query multiple times in one project?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-query

I'm making YouTube by myself.
I fetched the json file from the first page and got the data normally,

```
export default function VideoHome() {
  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data: popular,
  } = useQuery(["popular"], async () => {
    return fetch("data/popular.json").then((res) => res.json());
  });

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error}</p>;

  return (
    <div className={styles.video}>
      {popular.items.map((video) => (
        <VideoCard
          key={video.id}
          id={video.id}
          thumbnails={video.snippet.thumbnails.medium}
          title={video.snippet.title}
          channel={video.snippet.channelTitle}
          publish={video.snippet.publishedAt}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbMqo.png)

Create a search function and I used 'useNavigate' to move the page to search, where I used `query`, but I couldn't get the data

```
export default function VideoSearch() {
  const { search } = useParams();
  const { data: bts } = useQuery(["bts"], async () => {
    return fetch("data/bts.json").then((res) => res.json());
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {bts.items.map((value) => (
        <SearchVideoCard title={value.snippet.title} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I found it in the same way as the main page, but even if I use console, it outputs an `undefined`
error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/346Hb.png)
jsondata
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN6Za.png)

Comment: You have to check the `isLoading` and `error` variables, just like in the first function

Comment: I get this error when I use it.
`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Print the error message correctly. `{error.message}` https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/queries

Comment: I get this error
Error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Comment: A problem with your backend, then. Open the browser's network tab, look at what the backend sends for that request.

Comment: I think it's a matter of fetch path

Comment: I appreciate that
I don't think I know a lot yet I should work harder

Answer (score 0):

The error is informing you that `bts.items` is undefined on at least one render cycle, likely the initial render cycle until the query fetches the data and returns valid data.

The UI should account for the fetched data being not available yet, missing, malformed, etc. Don't forget to add a React key to the mapped array data.

Use the [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to access potentially undefined properties.

```
export default function VideoSearch() {
  const { search } = useParams();

  const { data: bts } = useQuery(["bts"], async () => {
    return fetch("data/bts.json").then((res) => res.json());
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {bts?.items?.map((value) => (
        <SearchVideoCard
          key={value.id.videoId}
          title={value.snippet.title}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You'll often likely prefer to render some fallback UI in the case there is no data to render. This is similar to your first snippet.

```
export default function VideoSearch() {
  const { search } = useParams();

  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data: bts
  } = useQuery(["bts"], async () => {
    return fetch("data/bts.json").then((res) => res.json());
  });

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error}</p>;

  if (!bts.items?.length) {
    return <div>No Data</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {bts.items?.map((value) => (
        <SearchVideoCard
          key={value.id.videoId}
          title={value.snippet.title}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that, I learned another thing!

Comment: When using this, if you enter a search term that is not made into a json file, a `syntaxError` will occur

Comment: @white Can you clarify what you mean in the last comment? Enter a search term where? Where does the error occur?

Comment: When I enter a search term, Load a file of '{search}. json' and upload it to the screen
I have two json file (bts.json, aespa.json)
So I searched for 'psy' that I didn't have, and after a few seconds, an error occurs
Isn't the phrase you told me the phrase you print out when there is no data to print out?

Comment: @white Are you saying that the returned query data is incorrect? I don't understand what any searching functionality has to do with the question. In either case though, it's never a bad idea to program defensively and handle potentially bad user input and/or missing data.

Comment: When non-existent data is requested, the 'No Data' you told me should be printed, right?

Comment: @white Yes, ideally something like that.

Comment: I have a search form, and for example, if the search term is 'bts', then ```const{
    isLoading,
    error,
    data: searchvideo,
  } } = useQuery(["searchvideo"], async () => {
    return fetch(`../../data/${search}.json`).then((res) => res.json());
  });
```
Send bts to search and bts.Json is 'map' to show a new page through 'useNavigate', and if you request the search term 'psy' here, it's normal for No Data to be printed like you said, but the error of 'error.message' will be printed

Comment: @white If I'm understanding your last comment correctly then I guess it comes down to if the user searches for some JSON file that doesn't exist that in the "error" state you return the "no data" UI instead of the error message.

Comment: Right! It's like asking for data that exists